# EGit won't add lib folder to vcs

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

I have a `lib` folder in my project, I've added it to my build path it even shows up in my .classpath but when I tried to commit it isn't committed.

I've tried adding it to GIT via eclipse but it won't work.

I havev tried adding it with the `git gui` but that says there aren't any files not added to Git.

How do I add it so that I can push it to GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure lib isn't ignore (listed in a .gitignore)

You can see it with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- lib
```

If it is, you can force the git add:

```
git add --force -- lib
```

---

The other reason might be that lib is a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) (but I suspect it isn't)